# IoT Core 14393 - FTP Schtask not executing upon boot

Tags: powershell, ftp, startup, windows-10-iot-core, dragonboard

I have successfully upgraded our DragonBoards 410c to IoT core build 14393.

As stated in the MS release notes

https://developer.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/iot/docs/releasenotesinsiderpreview

the FTP server is no longer loaded by default at startup.

I have tried to create a scheduler task as follows:

schtasks /create /tn IoTFTPD /tr ftpd.exe /ru system /sc onstart

The task was created successfully via PowerShell. The task can be executed manually via Powershell:

schtasks /run /tn IoTFTPD  (it will start the ftp server).

The problem is that the task does not execute upon startup of the device.

Any help is greatly appreciated.

Comment: I deleted my "answer" to increase the odds that someone else will come along with a real answer.

Comment: I have verified the tftpd task scheduler works on my raspberry pi 3, model B with windows IoT Core 10.0.14393.0.

Comment: I'm using putty over ssh to connect and create the scheduler task.

Comment: I have been using PS to create the scheduler task. It seems that only after issuing 'Set-ExecutionPolicy RemoteSigned' things work as expected. Thank you all for your comments!